# How can I create class for 2 dimentional array?

Tags: c++

I want to create class  by using generic programming to support the statement below

```
matrix<int, 2, 2> tonpai = { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } };
```

Thank you. // I'm trying to do this but I don't know what argument of constructor should be. sorry for my English. this is my first question.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise to understand how to do this, or because you need a tool that does it?

Comment: How about an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of [`std:array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Yes , I'm trying to do this exercise but I don't know what argument of constructor should be.

Comment: This is a complicated topic, especially if you want to allow the matrix to be `constexpr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your question is actually about how to make your class' constructor accept that kind of initializer list.  However, the commentors seem to think you are asking about how to implement a matrix class.

Just in case I'm right about this, here is an example of construction from an initializer list.

But if I'm wrong, keep in mind that this example's implementation of an array is bad and you don't want to use it.  I chose a C-Style static array just because it is simple to set up and people are familiar with how they work.

Also, this initialization will write outside the array's bounds if the list has too many elements, so keep that in mind for your class.

And I also assume you don't care about keeping your constructor constexpr.

So here it is, an example of a constructor accepting a 2-nested initializer list, only that...:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int row_count, int col_count>
class matrix {
    T carray[row_count][col_count];
public:
    matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<T> > init_list) {
        int rowidx=0;
        for(const auto& row : init_list) {
            int colidx=0;
            for(const auto& elem : row) {
                carray[rowidx][colidx++] = elem;
            }
            ++rowidx;
        }
    }

    void Print() const {
        for(const auto& row : carray) {
            for(const T& elem : row) {
                std::cout << elem << "  ";
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    matrix<int, 2, 2> tonpai = { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 } };
    tonpai.Print();
}
```

Comment: This is nice. Good job!

Comment: Thanks! (do you think that's what he's asking about? I didn't want to leave his cheese in the wind if so).

Comment: I do. (_"I don't know what argument of constructor should be"_)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have a lot of  problem about communicate in English. sorry again, I going to try and make it better